# Adding an element to a dictionary-type variable overwrites the existing value

Tags: google-apps-script

Adding an element to a dictionary-type variable in Google App Script causes the value to be overwritten.

For example, add the following values in order.

- A) Key: 'a1Y2r000002G9dS' Value: an array with 39 elements
- B) Key: 'a1Y2r000002IeA2' Value: array with 39 elements

A is added to the dictionary as follows.

```
var dict = {};
var keyA = 'a1Y2r000002G9dS';
var arrayA = ['aaaa',1,2,'bbbb',......] ;
var keyB = 'a1Y2r000002IeA2';
var arrayB = ['xxxx',0,3,'yyyy',......] ;

dict[keyA] = arrayA;.
```

At this point, the value of `dict[keyA]` is `arrayA`.
However, if I continue with `dict[keyB] = arrayB;`, the value of LineA changes to arrayB.

What is the cause?

I tried changing the dictionary type variable to a Map type variable, but the condition remains the same.

Comment: **the value of KeyA changes to arrayB.** I don't think so. Provide [mcve] (This isn't reproducible).